# Installing Lion on another MacBook Pro through a bootable DVD but won't show up

Tags: macos

I tried creating a bootable DVD of Lion, which was successful and would load in my MacBook Pro (already running Lion). I inserted the same DVD to another MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard, but it comes up as a blank CD... Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you create this bootable DVD? Can you provide some insight on how you achieved this, so that I can better identify your issue and give you a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Same as you : my brand new MBP cannot read a DVD (it says it is blank), but that same DVD can be read OK from older Macs. I went to an Apple store with that DVD, and they found the same problem, i.e. the DVD can be read OK on some machines, but not OK on others. I left them the DVD, they are going to enquire about it and about why some of their own machines can read and some others cannot.

So maybe your problem is just about that : a DVD which unluckily cannot be read on your machine.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Here's something I tried. I copied Install Mac OS X Lion.app to a USB, then pasted it in the Applications folder in the other MBP, then used Lion Disk Maker to burn it onto a DVD in that MBP-- when I mounted the disk, it worked! So maybe try that? Thanks for the input, too!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say. Do you have issues reading any other bootable DVDs/CDs on that device? I have had issues with my SuperDrive and because of it I actually created a bootable USB stick with Lion on it, worked perfectly.

You can find instructions on creating this bootable USB media here: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/11/build-your-own-lion-install-usb-thumb-drive-for-cheap/

Comment: Let me know how you go. Cheers.